# Short Imports with TypeScript Path Mapping in tsconfig

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths

I'm trying to create short importes for my Angular Modules.

Below is what I've modified in tsconfig.base.json file.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "paths": {
      "@asfc/shared": ["projects/asfc-shared/src"],
      "@asfc/shared/*": ["projects/asfc-shared/*"],
      "@asfc/shared/global": ["projects/asfc-shared/src/lib/global"],
      "@asfc/shared/global/*": ["projects/asfc-shared/src/lib/global/*"],
      "@asfc/shared/tagging": ["projects/asfc-shared/src/lib/tagging"],
      "@asfc/shared/tagging/*": ["projects/asfc-shared/src/lib/tagging/*"],
      "@asfc/shared/testing": ["projects/asfc-shared/src/lib/testing"]
    },
  "exclude": [
    "tools"
  ]
}
```

Module path: **projects/asfc-shared/src/public_api.ts**

```
export * from './lib/global/index';
export * from './lib/tagging/index';
export * from './lib/testing/index';
export * from './lib/shared/index';
```

In my component if I import, `SharedGlobalService`

```
import { SharedGlobalService } from '@asfc/shared';
```

I'm getting the below error.

```
ERROR: projects/ubc-security-profile/src/lib/apollo.config.ts:5:37 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@asfc/shared' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

What I'm doing wrong here ? Please help.

Update: Folder Structure

**Update**

After updating the baseUrl, I'm getting the below error

```
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
ERROR: Unable to write a reference to SvgCaptchaComponent in /Users/a1410978/Desktop/ssr-workspace/asfc-shell/projects/asfc-shared/src/lib/shared/svg-captcha/svg-captcha.component.ts from /Users/a1410978/Desktop/ssr-workspace/asfc-shell/projects/asfc-shared/src/lib/shared/svg-captcha/svg-captcha.module.ts
An unhandled exception occurred: Unable to write a reference to SvgCaptchaComponent in /Users/a1410978/Desktop/ssr-workspace/asfc-shell/projects/asfc-shared/src/lib/shared/svg-captcha/svg-captcha.component.ts from /Users/a1410978/Desktop/ssr-workspace/asfc-shell/projects/asfc-shared/src/lib/shared/svg-captcha/svg-captcha.module.ts
See "/private/var/folders/33/jgk04z2d26nbtr965nyz88fw0000gp/T/ng-yirb2X/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Answer (score 1):

Paths are relative to the `baseUrl` value.

Example... if your `tsconfig.json` lives at the project root, and your Angular application code lives in `src`, also at the root, you can specify the `baseUrl` as `src`.

From there, paths start at `src`.

Let's say you have a `src -> lib` directory and want to make a path for that:

```
"paths": {
  "@app/lib/*": ["app/lib/*"]
}
```

Then you can reference an import as:

```
import { yourExport } from '@app/lib/wherever';
```

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: I've updated my folder structure, I've set my baseUrl as `./`

Comment: If you've set the `baseUrl` to `./`, your paths look correct based on your sample code. I've noticed sometimes Visual Studio Code, if that's what you're using, can be very slow to pick up these changes, and sometimes I have to close it and re-launch it to get the paths to register.

Comment: Is there a way to specify shortcuts inside the library, not the client? It seems a bit usless to force each client to setup the shortcuts.